# Estimate (Calculate) List Integration Error

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

This is my "List Integrate" function:

```
fListInt[list_, start_, end_, order_] :=   Integrate[  
Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> order][x], {x, start,    
end}]
```

Suppose I have a list of experimental data points, dataL (for example of data structure: RandomReal[{10, 15}, 100]) and a list of the Standard Error for each point errorL (for example: RandomReal[{0.1, 0.5}, 100]).

How would I calculate the error (or at least get an approximation) of fListInt[dataL,1,100,1]?